# Nginx - Redis Server issue

Tags: nginx, redis

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 VPS with multiple WP sites running in Nginx (Used this tutorial: https://deliciousbrains.com/hosting-wordpress-setup-secure-virtual-server/)

When enabling Redis Server somehow all websites redirect to the first enabled site in Nginx. Turning off Redis Server solves the issue.

I've installed Redis-Server using this link: https://deliciousbrains.com/hosting-wordpress-yourself-server-monitoring-caching/

Any suggestions how to solve this? No additional configuration should be needed according the tutorial.

Cheers,
Jaap

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;  
worker_processes 2;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections 2048;
multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 15;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
server_tokens off;
client_max_body_size 64m;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 2;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Cache Settings
##

add_header Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

##
# SSL
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem;

#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name _;
return 444;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you're "enabling" Redis Server?

Comment: @ceejayoz  
- sudo apt-get install redis-server  
- sudo apt-get install php5-redis  
- sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf, uncomment maxmemory and set to 64mb   - sudo service redis-server restart - sudo service php5-fpm restart  
  
See https://deliciousbrains.com/hosting-wordpress-yourself-server-monitoring-caching/  

Strange thing is I used the same tutorial for another VPS and there it's working just fine.

Comment: *Just* those steps cause it to do this? Or did you make the `fastcgi_cache_path` changes later in that document? I'd guess the issue lies there with the cache paths, not merely turning on redis.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, I also made the fastcgi_cache_path changes. All sites have their own keys_zone name and the "fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";" is in the nginx.conf.